# Intel Media SDK getting MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED creating second encoder

Tags: media, device, intel, encoder, decoder

I'm using the intel media sdk under windows 8.1 to encode/decode several streams. The problem I have is under Hardware mode when I try to initiate a second encoder the function returns MFX_ERR_DEVICE_FAILED, but the first encoder is correctly initialized.

Under software mode there is no problem at all. I can generate all encoders.

does anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using different sessions for each HW encoder? If not, that is not correct. You can look at sample_multi_transcode example provided to understand how to initiate multiple media pipelines. https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-media-server-studio-support/code-samples